# how to make javaservice for the .net application?

Tags: java, .net, web-services, service, java-service-wrapper

Can Anyone Please Tell me How can i make service for the java application that can be use by .net application?

i m using wcf in my .net application..i had use to process the executable jar file with command line argument from my .net application but that will be very slow in real scenario.

So How can i just use java application from the .net application that run on service  and just provide me some values as a parameter to execute jar file on the service..

Which one i can use to make my java service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Done that With the use of axis2 in Apache tomcat server..at last i have found